# Angular - display a string property, defined in Child... in the Parent

Tags: angular

If I have a property (a string) that is defined in a child component, how could I display that in a parent component? All the examples I see, seem to involve click events / Event Emmitter. But what if there is no event required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Talking from Child to Parent

There are a couple of different ways to talk from child to parent to choose from depending on the usecase:

You shouldn't get confused by the 'event'. It is just an event you create in the child as a way to talk to the parent. There doesn't need to be any user triggered event like clicks or anything.

#### With ViewChild

In parent.component.ts:

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  value = 'My Value';

  @ViewChild(SecondChildComponent) someChild!: any

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.value = this.someChild.someValue
  }
```

In child.component.ts:

```js
someValue = 'New Value'
```

*This value is only read 'AfterViewInit'. The parent would need some sort of event to update the value when it gets changed in the child component.*

#### With EventEmitter Output

In child.component.ts:

```js
@Output() someEvent = new EventEmitter

someFunction(): void {
  this.someEvent.emit('Some data...')
}
```

In parent template:

```html
<app-child (someEvent)="handleSomeEvent($event)"></app-child>
```

In parent.component.ts:

```js
handleSomeEvent(event: any): void {
  // Do something
}
```

#### Over a Router Outlet

We can use the onActivate method to get a reference to the component that gets loaded into the router-outlet.

In child.component.ts:

```js
@Output() deleteEvent = new EventEmitter
@Output() addEvent = new EventEmitter

deleteItem(id){
    this.deleteEvent.emit(id)
}
  addItem(data) {
    this.deleteEvent.emit(data)
}
```

In the parent template:

```html
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

In parent.component.ts:

```js
onActivate(componentReference) {
   componentReference.deleteEvent.subscribe((id) => {
      // implementation
   });

   componentReference.addEvent.subscribe((data) => {
      // implementation
   })
}
```

#### With a Service

We can also use a data service bound to root to share data between unrelated components. This is also useful when a lot of other components need to access the shared data.

In service:

```js
private sharedValue = new BehaviorSubject('')
currentSharedValue = this.sharedValue.asObservable()

changeSharedValue(newValue: string) {
  this.sharedValue.next(newValue)
}
```

Component changing data:

```js
constructor(
  private dataService: DataService
) { }

changeSharedData(): void {
  this.dataService.changeSharedValue('New Shared Data')
}
```

Component reading shared data:

```js
value = 'Old Value'
subscription!: Subscription;

constructor(
  private dataService: DataService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.dataService.currentSharedValue.subscribe(newValue => {
    this.value = newValue
  })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```